# Java Button for program

Tags: java, swing

Im in need of help with my java program code. Basically it is a program that allows users to request an item and the amount they want. If it is in stock they can click a "buy" button. Once clicked a confirm dialog will pop up asking if the user will like to buy 'x' units for 'y' amount. They can either choose yes, no or cancel. If they choose yes a pop up frame with the reciept will come up (havent done this part yet). The problem that i am having is that if they click no or cancel the reciept frame still shows - I dont want it to do this. Please can you tell me what is wrong with my code as it is not performing how i want it to perform. p.s. im a beginner in java as ive only been learning for a month

```
enter code here

public PurchaseItem() {

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  

    JPanel top = new JPanel();
    top.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    bottom.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    bottom.add(Buy);
    this.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 250);
    setTitle("Purchase Item");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    top.add(new JLabel("Enter Item Key:"));
    top.add(ItemNo);
    top.add(new JLabel ("Enter Amount:"));
    top.add(AmountNo);
    top.add(check);

    Buy.setText("Buy"); Buy.setVisible(true);

    check.addActionListener(this);
    Buy.addActionListener(this);

    add("North", top);
    JPanel middle = new JPanel();
    middle.add(information);
    add("Center", middle);

    setResizable(true);
    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String ItemKey = ItemNo.getText();          
    String ItemAmount = AmountNo.getText();
    String Name = StockData.getName(ItemKey);

    int Yes = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
    int No = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;    

    int Amount = Integer.parseInt(ItemAmount);
    int Key = Integer.parseInt(ItemKey);

    int NewStock = StockData.getQuantity(ItemKey) - Amount;

    double Total = Integer.parseInt(ItemAmount) * StockData.getPrice(ItemKey);

    if (Name == null){
       information.setText("There is no such item");
    }
    else if (Amount > StockData.getQuantity(ItemKey)) {
    information.setText("Sorry there is not enough stock available");
}
    else {
        information.setText(Name + " selected: " + ItemAmount);
        information.append("\nIndividual Unit Price: " + pounds.format(StockData.getPrice(ItemKey)));
        information.append("\nCurrent Stock Available: " + StockData.getQuantity(ItemKey));
        information.append("\nNew Stock After Sale: " + NewStock);
        information.append("\n\nTotal: " + ItemAmount + " Units" + " at  " + pounds.format(StockData.getPrice(ItemKey)) + " each");
        information.append("\n= " + pounds.format(Total));
    }        
    if (e.getSource() ==  Buy) {          
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Buy " + ItemAmount + " Units" + " for " + pounds.format(Total) + "?");
        if (Yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
        frame2.pack(); frame2.setBounds(250, 250, 500, 500); frame2.setTitle("Reciept"); frame2.setVisible(true);
        JPanel middle = new JPanel();
        middle.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        middle.add(reciept);
        reciept.setBounds(260,260,400,400);
        reciept.setVisible(true);
        }


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (Yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {` is always `true` (`Yes` been equal to `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION`; `int Yes = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;`).

You need to get the return value from `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` and compare that

```
int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Buy " + ItemAmount + " Units" + " for " + pounds.format(Total) + "?");
if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean there

Comment: Really? Basically your saying `if (1 == 1)` which is always `true` regardless of what the user might respond with.  `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` returns the "action" the use choose, so you need to compare the response with the action you're interested. See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks i figured how to do it and it works fine now :)